# Python's ftplib with tqdm

Tags: python, ftplib, tqdm

I have a console script which uses [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) as a backend to get a number of files from an ftp server. I would like to use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) to give the user some feedback provided they have a "verbose" switch on.  This *must* be optional as some users might use the script without `tty` access.

The [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html)'s `retrbinary` method takes a callback so it should be possible to hook [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) in there somehow. However, I have no idea what this callback would look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `FTP.retrbinary`:

> The callback function is called for each block of data received, with a single string argument giving the data block.

So the callback could be something like:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    total = ftpclient.size(filename)

    with tqdm(total=total) as pbar:
        def callback_(data):
            l = len(data)
            pbar.update(l)
            fd.write(data)

        ftpclient.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(filename), callback_)
```

**Beware:** This code is untested and probably has to be adapted.

Comment: After implementing this, it needs a few more checks to handle bad blocks.                                                 `if (raw_file.tell() == filesize): tqdm_instance.close()`

Answer (score 2):

That code shouldn't work as `pbar` will be "closed" when the `with` block terminates, which occurs just before `ftpclient.retrbinary(...)`. You need a very minor indentation mod:

```py
with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    total = ftpclient.size(filename)

    with tqdm(total=total,
              unit='B', unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024, 
              disable=not verbose) as pbar:
        def cb(data):
            pbar.update(len(data))
            fd.write(data)

        ftpclient.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(filename), cb)
```

**EDIT** added `disable` flag and bytes scaling

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    total = ftpclient.size(filename)

    with tqdm(total=total,
              unit='B', unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024, 
              disable=not verbose) as pbar:
        def cb(data):
            pbar.update(len(data))
            fd.write(data)

        ftpclient.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(filename), cb)
```